# mvn test and compile

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, webdriver

We write tests in Java+Webdriver+Eclipse and run them using Maven.
To start the application, we need to start one java file - STARTAPP.java/class

So, if we start the tests run (for the first time), we should write like:
mvn test -Dtest=STARTAPP,myfirsttestname

And for the next time onwards, shall we skip the STARTAPP
(e.g.: mvn test -Dtest=mysecondtestname

Does the test goal, compile the java file?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

> Does the test goal, compile the java file?

[Test](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) goal doesn't compile any java classes itself. It's done by maven compiler plugin goals 'compile' and 'testCompile'. But since test goal goes after compile goals, then you will have your java classes compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Build phase `test` is preceded by build phase `compile`, during which the source code of the project is compiled. Take a look at [Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) in Maven.